Page Break between subtables
I'm very new to LaTeX and I am trying to introduce a page break between sub-tables, to prevent the table from running off the bottom of the page, however, even with the \newpage after table c, table d is still running off the page. I have also tried \clearpage and had the same problem. Am I able to wrap all of the subtables into a longtable?:
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Results of contrasts for treatments tested in H1.}

% Table for (a) How x affects y
\subcaption{How x affects y}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
Group Comparison & Mean Difference & SE & t.ratio & p-Value \\
\hline
% Data
\hline
\label{tab:H1a}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}

% Table for (b) How x affects z)
\subcaption{How x affects z}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
Group Comparison & Estimate & SE & t-ratio & p-Value \\
\hline
% Data
\hline
\label{tab:H1b}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}

% Table for (c) How x affects t
\subcaption{How x affects t}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
Group Comparison & Estimate & SE & t-ratio & p-value \\
\hline
% Data
\hline
\label{tab:H1c}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}
\newpage

% Table for (d) How x affects u
\subcaption{How x affects u}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
Group Comparison & Estimate & SE & t-ratio & p-Value \\
\hline
% Data omitted
\hline
\label{tab:H1d}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}

% Table for (e) How x affects v)
\subcaption{How x affects v}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
Group Comparison & Estimate & SE & t-ratio & p-Value \\
\hline
% Data omitted
\hline
\label{tab:H1e}
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 



A table environment does not allow page breaks. You could split your subtables into several environments and use \ContinuedFloat from the caption package to continue the numbering.

Fantastic thank you, that has solved the issue!

You're welcome!

Welcome to TeX.SE!

BTW: It is always better to show a complete document instead of a code snippet only.  If we first need to complete the document, we would, e.g., not know the page size of your document and therefore where the page break should happen. Also guessing which package are needed to compile code is always a source of misunderstandings. So to be able to reproduce a problem by copy&paste + LaTeX is always the better thing.
